# Using preg_replace isn't working as I expect

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Well, I'm trying to do something very simple but turns out it's pretty complicated.
I have this string which is -

> post/6

And for example and I want to replace it with  -

> post/view/6

so I tried to replace it using the following pattern -

> /post/[1-9-a-z]/

And the replacement pattern -

> view/$0

But for some reason, the string that's returned is this string -

> /view/post/6

Maybe you guys know the solution for this?
I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use
Search Pattern

```
~post/([1-9-a-z])~
```

with Replacement Pattern

```
post/view/$1
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple but still helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `str_replace()` no regex is required:

```
echo str_replace('post/', 'post/view/', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I also need to validate the string, so basically I must use regex

Answer (score 1):

This is expected result

`$0` represents the complete string that has been matched i.e `post/6` in your case

You can use lookaround

```
preg_replace('/(?<=post)(?=\/[\da-z])/',"/view",$txt);
```

OR

```
preg_replace('/(post)(\/[\da-z])/',"$1/view$2",$txt);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I couldn't understand your code because I'm not that good in regular expression, but still, thanks.

Comment: @Yehonatan see this [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)